# In pymongo is there any map reduce alternatives aside from using inline-like javascript?

Tags: python, mongodb

I think it gets really dirty and unmaintainable writing javascript in a heredoc and passing it to the bson Code class. Are there any alternatives to writing it like this? Potentially in a separate javascript file and import it somehow?  My entire script is below and there is still 40-50 more lines of code to add to the map and reduce.

```
#!/usr/bin/env
from pymongo import *
from bson.code import Code

mclient = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
maindb = mclient['tester']['articles']

map = Code("""function () {
            var obj = {
              id: this.id,
              timeseries_valid: true,
            }
            var comment_count=0;

            function loopAndSet(timeseries, count){
              for (var i = 0; i < timeseries.length; i++) { 
                if (i[1] < count){
                  obj.timeseries_valid = false;
                }
                count = i[1];
              }
            }

            if (this.comment_count_timeseries && this.comment_count_timeseries.length > 1) {
              loopAndSet(this.comment_count_timeseries, comment_count);
            }
            emit(this.id, obj);
        }""")

reduce = Code("""function (k, v) { return v[0]; }""")
maindb.map_reduce(map, reduce, "idsValid")
```

Comment: Not looking at the code itself, but a suggestion: save your javascript in some .js files which you load from disk with open and read, and then pass the variables contents to the python code which needs them. Other solution, save the map and the reduce functions inside mongo itself, then call the map-reduces functions by their names

Comment: @BlakesSeven the point is not the evaluate the code. i've mentioned that it it is not even finished; but rather the implementation of porting the JS over to python commands.

Comment: @Apero thanks for your comment. If you could write an example below. I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Funny how I could point out that if you actually expressed what you wanted to do here then there are logically better alternatives to running JavaScript. As said the code here clearly does not work for whatever the intended purpose is. It is likely this is not the only example. And therefore there are better alternates that save you all the trouble. But if you don't want the help, then don't bother answering the queries raised and just get something that won't actually help in return.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I have a collection of article documents. each document has a key ['comment_count_timeseries'] with nested arrays as the value. the second item in each array is the amount of comments for the article retrieved via api.  (please don't inquire about the structure i didn't build it) Sometimes the api sends bad data ie, comment_count:0 comment_count:-100. This mapper function iterates over the collection and determines if the next comment timeseries value is lower than the previous. Being that the comment count cannot decrease; this will determine that this data is suspicious

Comment: @BlakesSeven Now my question is: Because I need to add more code to the mapper, is there a way to clean it up possibly; by importing over a javascript file that contains the map function in order to clean up my python file.

Comment: No No No. Now your question is nothing more than you actually ask directly in your question content. There is an edit link there that I suggest you use ( and did from the start despite the other noise here ) to clarify your real intent rather than ask the question you asked. If you want an answer then please fix your question and then notify me.

Comment: @BlakesSeven ok. after re-reading your comment. thank you for pointing out the error in my code. it was a misunderstanding on my end. my question still stands.

Comment: You need to explain what you want to really achieve here otherwise there is no question to be answered. It is why you have no answer, and just providing "load JavaScript like this" will not help you. You are not doing things the right way, which is exactly what I am trying to help you with. There are faster and more efficient ways to do what I suspect you are trying to do. Please alter your question to explain it or don't respond to me and get a bad response in return. Your choice.